# tkinter Button printing same thing multiple times

Tags: python, debugging, tkinter

I am currently working on a little just for fun project, which pretends it´s generating something and then shows a specific message, but I have a question: As soon as I press the button on the screen it is showing a progressbar, that is what I want it to do, but if I press the button again it just shows the same thing again and again, is there any way to prevent the program from printing the Starting the generate text and the progressbar multiple times?

Here´s the code:

```
# my little import area
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

# Initialization
win = tk.Tk()
win.title("StackOverflow")

# Window Size
win.resizable(False, False)
win.minsize(750,500)

# Button clicked command
def buttonclicked():
    tk.Label(win, text="Starting to generate...").pack()
    pb.pack()
    pb.start(500)

#Widgets

headerlabel = tk.Label(win, text="StackOverFlow Question")
generatebutton = tk.Button(win, text="Generate", command=buttonclicked)
pb = ttk.Progressbar(win, orient="horizontal", length=250, mode="determinate")

#Positioning
headerlabel.pack()
generatebutton.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put

```
global generatebutton
generatebutton.config(state='disabled')
```

in your buttonclicked function (which is stupid because the `global` keyword is usually SO BAD to use, it turns your code into nightmare), or use OOP to your advantage. You can also use `win.destroy()` or `generatebutton.destroy()`.

Here is that more OOP-intensive code example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Joke:
    def __init__(self):
        self.win = tk.Tk()
        self.win.title("StackOverflow")

        self.win.resizable(False, False)
        self.win.minsize(750,500)

        headerlabel = tk.Label(self.win, text="StackOverFlow Question")
        self.generatebutton = tk.Button(self.win, text="Generate", command=self.buttonclicked)
        self.pb = ttk.Progressbar(self.win, orient="horizontal", length=250, mode="determinate")

        headerlabel.pack()
        self.generatebutton.pack()

        self.win.mainloop()

    def buttonclicked(self):
        tk.Label(self.win, text="Starting to generate...").pack()
        self.pb.pack()
        self.pb.start(500)
        self.generatebutton.config(state='disabled')

Joke()
```

Hope that's helpful!